# Yet another NSScanner characterSetWithCharactersInString newb

Tags: objective-c, nsscanner

Let's assume I have a string ("G00 X0.0000 Y0.0000") and I need to to parse its contents. Here is my code:

```
NSCharacterSet *params = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"XY"];

//setup the scanner
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringToBeScanned];
NSString *scanned = nil;

//scan the string
NSLog(@"%@", stringToBeScanned);
while ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:params intoString:&scanned]) {

    struct keypair code;
    code.key = [scanned characterAtIndex:0];
    code.value = [[scanned substringFromIndex:1] doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"--> %@ [%lu]= (%c, %.4f)", scanned, [scanner scanLocation], code.key, code.value);
}
```

And the output to NSLog:

```
G00 X0.0000 Y0.0000 
--> G00  [4]= (G, 0.0000)
```

My characterSet includes both 'X' and 'Y' and I can't figure out why my NSScanner won't scan in the 'X0.0000 ' - it should find that Y and pull in everything from X up to Y according to my understanding.

I can see from the scanLocation that the scanner is stopping at index 4 (correctly), but the loop either doesn't continue or evaluates to false. Shouldn't the scanner keep looping and finding my delimiters (from the characterSet) and grabbing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:` scans *up to* the "X" and gives you the characters it scanned "G00 ".

*Note that it does not scan the "X".* When you call the method again, it looks at the next character (the "X"), notices that it is a character in the set, and stops scanning. As it scanned no characters, it then returns `NO`.

To scan the "X" (or "Y"), you will want to use `scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:` as well.

Comment: oh. you are saying that in order for it continue scanning that string and pass by the x (scanUpTo: "Y") -- i'd have to remove the "X" from the characterSet? hmm... there are a number of different characters I could encounter and need to take different actions based on which character I encounter (not just X and Y). Is there a different way you could suggest to do this? I was trying to make it as compact and efficient as possible.

Comment: thanks for the info. using this information I have added my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Basically I receive a string with a list of "codes" followed by a value associated with that command/parameter. There could several different "commands" in each string, or none at all. The key was to use scanCharactersFromSet: and scanUpToCharactersFromSet: in order to capture the right pairings and parse the entire string while staying very flexible. It's a little ugly, I know.

Here is my code:

```
//setup the scanner
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[self stringByAppendingString:@"!"]];
NSCharacterSet *codeset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"GMTFIJKPRSXYZ!"];
NSString *scanned = nil;
char codechar;

//perform the first scan
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:codeset intoString:&scanned];
if (scanned)
    codechar = [scanned characterAtIndex:0];

//scan the string
while ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:codeset intoString:&scanned]) {
    struct keypair code;
    code.key = codechar;
    code.value = [scanned doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"--> (%c, %.4f)", code.key, code.value);

    //skip over the delimeter we encountered
    [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:codeset intoString:&scanned];
    if (scanned)
        codechar = [scanned characterAtIndex:0];

}
```